# Noise and distortion in Swift implementation of SDL audio callback

Tags: swift, macos, sdl, audiobuffer

I'm currently building a game music player in Swift for Mac OS, using [GME](https://bitbucket.org/mpyne/game-music-emu/src/master/gme/) for generating sound buffers and [SDL](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryAudio) for audio playback. I have previously (and successfully) used [SDL_QueueAudio](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_QueueAudio?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAudio%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29) for playback, but I need more fine tuned control over the buffer handling in order to determine song progress, song end etc. So, that leaves me with SDL_AudioCallback in the [SDL_AudioSpec](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AudioSpec?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryStruct%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryAudio%29) API.

I CAN hear the song play, but it's accompanied by noise and distortion (and sometimes echo depending on what I try).

**Setup**

```
var desiredSpec = SDL_AudioSpec()
desiredSpec.freq = Int32(44100)
desiredSpec.format = SDL_AudioFormat(AUDIO_U8)
desiredSpec.samples = 512
desiredSpec.channels = 2
desiredSpec.callback = { callback(userData: $0, stream: $1, length: $2) }

SDL_OpenAudio(&desiredSpec, nil)
```

**Callback**

```
func callback(userData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, stream: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?, length: Int32) {
    // Half sample length to compensate for double byte Int16.
    var output = Array<Int16>.init(repeating: 0, count: Int(length / 2))

    // Generates stereo signed Int16 audio samples.
    gme_play(emulator, Int32(output.count), &output)

    // Converts Int16 samples to UInt8 samples expected by the mixer below. Then adds to buffer.
    var buffer = [UInt8]()
    for i in 0 ..< (output.count) {
        let uIntVal = UInt16(bitPattern: output[i])
        buffer.append(UInt8(uIntVal & 0xff))
        buffer.append(UInt8((uIntVal >> 8) & 0xff))
    }

    SDL_MixAudio(stream, buffer, Uint32(length), SDL_MIX_MAXVOLUME)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!
In the end this was enough to make it work:

```
desiredSpec.format = SDL_AudioFormat(AUDIO_S16)

var buffer = Array<Int16>(repeating: 0, count: Int(length / 2))
gme_play(emulator, Int32(output.count), &output)
SDL_memcpy(stream, buffer, Int(length))
```